# How to use jQuery get method with ASP.NET MVC controller actions?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

I want to use jQuery get method with a partial view. What is the best way to do it? I read about [jQuery get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) and the simplest way to me is this code:

```
$.get(@Url.Action('Controller', 'Action'), function () { });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are just missing quotes around the url and have messed up the `Url.Action` helper syntax. Here's the correct way:

```
$.get('@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")', function (result) { 
    // TODO: process the results of the server side call
});
```

Notice the single quotes around the url passed to the $.get method and the signature of the Url.Action helper.

Comment: Yeah, what a silly ignorance by me. Thanks. But any idea about the practicality of this method?

Comment: @Saeed Neamati, the practicality to do what? If it is for doing AJAX requests, yeah, it's great.